Layout management cannot create a print layout
When I want to create a new layout in the layout management, a window opens in which a title can be assigned. This window is grayed out. I cannot enter anything there. I am currently working with QGis 3.38. The problem also occurs with many other versions (3.22, 3.34, ...).
I can also open existing layouts, but not rename or duplicate them. The problem occurs both when opening a template and an empty layout. I have already tried everything. The fact that it does not work with every version means that I do not suspect the respective version but another problem.
It occurs regardless of the project. It simply occurred in an existing project in which layouts could already be created without any problems. I have had the problem for about a week. I have already carried out several restarts.

You may have to replace your QGIS app data folder, which isn't changed with any new install or reinstall.  C:\Users\your user name here\AppData\Roaming\QGIS.  If you have a lot of customizations you could rename it, QGIS will recreate a new one and if that doesn't fix things delete the new one and replace it by renaming your original back to its original name.
